# Is $B - B'$ self-adjoint provided $B,B'$ are positive operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If I have two positive operators $B,B'$ on an arbitrary Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ not necessarily over $\mathbb{C}$, how do I know that $B - B'$ is self adjoint?

EDIT: Reed and Simon define positiveness of an operator $B$ as follows: We say that an operator $B \colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is positive if for every $x \in \mathcal{H}$,
$
\langle x,Bx \rangle \ge 0 \,.
$

Comment: Does "positive" include "self-adjoint" in the definition?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I have added the definition that is used in the textbook. The authors point out that every positive operator is self-adjoint provided $\mathcal{H}$ is a \emph{complex} Hilbert space. Then in a later proof this is not assumed, yet the operator $B- B'$ is claimed to be self-adjoint without further comment.

Comment: Well, then it's not true. Let $B$ be a positive non-self-adjoint operator and $B'$ a multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer said: if this is how positivity is defined, and if the ground field is $\mathbb R$, then the statement is false. Just let $B'$ be the zero operator, and let $B$ be any non-self-adjoint positive operator such as
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
The authors either implicitly switched to the more common definition of positivity (which requires self-adjointness), or omitted a hypothesis.